# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_xxxx", referenced from:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

This problem won't happen while I'm using simulator.
But it happens while I build on my device.

As I checked Stackoverflow, I have already added QuartzCoer, CFNetwork adn Security.framework.But the error is still there.
Below is error details:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCDAsyncUdpSocket", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.GCDAsyncUdpSocket in FreePicViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Add the code you're having trouble with

Comment: I solved it as below link:
[link](https://github.com/jdiehl/async-network/issues/3)